# Meaning of 取り消してくれ in this sentence

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension, giving-and-receiving

Earlier on, dad said that he might run away rather than protect his daughter. Circumstances have forced him to claim that he has changed his mind;

> 「えっ？　オレだってちゃんとしてやるさ」
>   Eh? Even I would do the right thing.
>
> 「じゃあ、このまえ言ったことは取り消しだね？」
>   So, it's a retraction of what you said earlier?
>
> 「おう。**取り消してくれ**。オレは家族を守るぞ」
>   ??? I will protect the family.

I don't understand the part in bold. Why is it imperative? It sounds to me like he is instructing his daughter to retract what she just said. But I was expecting him just to admit that he had retracted his earlier statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed an instruction to his daughter to retract the previous statement. But he's referring to *his own* previous statement.

> じゃあ、このまえ言ったことは取り消しだね？
>   So, are you cancelling what you said earlier?
>
> おう。取り消してくれ。オレは家族を守るぞ
>   Um. Cancel it [for me], would you? I will protect my family.

I'd like to translate it with "Are you taking back what you said earlier?" and "I take it back" but this is precisely confusing the literal meaning of ～てくれ, so I chose to translate it with "cancel" (= "take off the record") instead.